# Simple Cursor Adapter and Listview

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview, simplecursoradapter

I have a Listview that should show all entries from database in my main activity. I'm using a Simple Cursor Adapter, but when I run as android application, it crashes. The application is stopped and finished. Something wrong is happenning.

Trace of the Crash

```
    03-27 00:23:50.555: E/cm value(1589): false
03-27 00:23:59.643: E/AndroidRuntime(1589): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-27 00:23:59.643: E/AndroidRuntime(1589): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ec.idiomas/com.ec.idiomas.BancoDictionary}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: selectionArgs must be provided for the Uri: content://com.ec.idiomas.searchabledict.DictionaryProvider/dictionary
03-27 00:23:59.643: E/AndroidRuntime(1589):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
03-27 00:23:59.643: E/AndroidRuntime(1589):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
03-27 00:23:59.643: E/AndroidRuntime(1589):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
03-27 00:23:59.643: E/AndroidRuntime(1589):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
03-27 00:23:59.643: E/AndroidRuntime(1589):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-27 00:23:59.643: E/AndroidRuntime(1589):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-27 00:23:59.643: E/AndroidRuntime(1589):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
03-27 00:23:59.643: E/AndroidRuntime(1589):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-27 00:23:59.643: E/AndroidRuntime(1589):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-27 00:23:59.643: E/AndroidRuntime(1589):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
03-27 00:23:59.643: E/AndroidRuntime(1589):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-27 00:23:59.643: E/AndroidRuntime(1589):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-27 00:23:59.643: E/AndroidRuntime(1589): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: selectionArgs must be provided for the Uri: content://com.ec.idiomas.searchabledict.DictionaryProvider/dictionary
03-27 00:23:59.643: E/AndroidRuntime(1589):     at com.ec.idiomas.DictionaryProvider.query(DictionaryProvider.java:62)
03-27 00:23:59.643: E/AndroidRuntime(1589):     at android.content.ContentProvider.query(ContentProvider.java:652)
03-27 00:23:59.643: E/AndroidRuntime(1589):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.query(ContentProvider.java:189)
03-27 00:23:59.643: E/AndroidRuntime(1589):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:370)
03-27 00:23:59.643: E/AndroidRuntime(1589):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:313)
03-27 00:23:59.643: E/AndroidRuntime(1589):     at com.ec.idiomas.BancoDictionary.onCreate(BancoDictionary.java:107)
03-27 00:23:59.643: E/AndroidRuntime(1589):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
03-27 00:23:59.643: E/AndroidRuntime(1589):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
03-27 00:23:59.643: E/AndroidRuntime(1589):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
03-27 00:23:59.643: E/AndroidRuntime(1589):     ... 11 more
```

My Main Activity

```
public class BancoDictionary extends ListActivity  {

public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile1";


ListView mListView;




@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.main);


mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);





Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(DictionaryProvider.CONTENT_URI, new String[] {DictionaryDatabase.KEY_WORD, DictionaryDatabase.KEY_DEFINITION}, null, null, null);
startManagingCursor(cursor);


String[] columns = new String[] { DictionaryDatabase.KEY_WORD, DictionaryDatabase.KEY_DEFINITION };

int[] to = new int[] { R.id.word, R.id.definition };


SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, cursor, columns, to);





mListView.setListAdapter(mAdapter);
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
Intent wordIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WordActivity.class);
Uri data = Uri.withAppendedPath(DictionaryProvider.CONTENT_URI,
                            String.valueOf(id));


wordIntent.setData(data);
wordIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
wordIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
startActivity(wordIntent);

}


});

}

}
```

DictionaryProvider

```
public class DictionaryProvider extends ContentProvider {
String TAG = "DictionaryProvider";

public static String AUTHORITY = "com.ec.idiomas.searchabledict.DictionaryProvider";
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/dictionary");

public static final String WORDS_MIME_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_DIR_BASE_TYPE +
                                              "/vnd.ec.idiomas.searchabledict";
public static final String DEFINITION_MIME_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_ITEM_BASE_TYPE +
                                                   "/vnd.eci.idiomas.searchabledict";

private DictionaryDatabase mDictionary;

private static final int SEARCH_WORDS = 0;
private static final int GET_WORD = 1;
private static final int SEARCH_SUGGEST = 2;
private static final int REFRESH_SHORTCUT = 3;
private static final UriMatcher sURIMatcher = buildUriMatcher();

private static UriMatcher buildUriMatcher() {
    UriMatcher matcher =  new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "dictionary", SEARCH_WORDS);
    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "dictionary/#", GET_WORD);
    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY, SEARCH_SUGGEST);
    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY + "/*", SEARCH_SUGGEST);

    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_SHORTCUT, REFRESH_SHORTCUT);
    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_SHORTCUT + "/*", REFRESH_SHORTCUT);
    return matcher;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    mDictionary = new DictionaryDatabase(getContext());
    return true;
}

@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs,
                    String sortOrder) {

    switch (sURIMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case SEARCH_SUGGEST:
            if (selectionArgs == null) {
              throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                  "selectionArgs must be provided for the Uri: " + uri);
            }
            return getSuggestions(selectionArgs[0]);
        case SEARCH_WORDS:
            if (selectionArgs == null) {
              throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                  "selectionArgs must be provided for the Uri: " + uri);
            }
            return search(selectionArgs[0]);
        case GET_WORD:
            return getWord(uri);
        case REFRESH_SHORTCUT:
            return refreshShortcut(uri);
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown Uri: " + uri);
    }
}

private Cursor getSuggestions(String query) {
  query = query.toLowerCase();
  String[] columns = new String[] {
      BaseColumns._ID,
      DictionaryDatabase.KEY_WORD,

      SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID};

  return mDictionary.getWordMatches(query, columns);
}

private Cursor search(String query) {
  query = query.toLowerCase();
  String[] columns = new String[] {
      BaseColumns._ID,
      DictionaryDatabase.KEY_WORD,
      DictionaryDatabase.KEY_DEFINITION};

  return mDictionary.getWordMatches(query, columns);
}

private Cursor getWord(Uri uri) {
  String rowId = uri.getLastPathSegment();
  String[] columns = new String[] {
      DictionaryDatabase.KEY_WORD,
      DictionaryDatabase.KEY_DEFINITION};

  return mDictionary.getWord(rowId, columns);
}

private Cursor refreshShortcut(Uri uri) {

  String rowId = uri.getLastPathSegment();
  String[] columns = new String[] {
      BaseColumns._ID,
      DictionaryDatabase.KEY_WORD,
      DictionaryDatabase.KEY_DEFINITION,
      SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID,
      SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID};

  return mDictionary.getWord(rowId, columns);
}

@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {
    switch (sURIMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case SEARCH_WORDS:
            return WORDS_MIME_TYPE;
        case GET_WORD:
            return DEFINITION_MIME_TYPE;
        case SEARCH_SUGGEST:
            return SearchManager.SUGGEST_MIME_TYPE;
        case REFRESH_SHORTCUT:
            return SearchManager.SHORTCUT_MIME_TYPE;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URL " + uri);
    }
}

@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}

@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}

@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

}

Comment: Does the stack trace of the crash not help you?

Comment: @DougStevenson No, it doesn't. I'm a newbie. And I am testing it directly on my smartphone.

Comment: That doesn't mean you can't see and show us a stack trace.  If there is a crash, you should always share the stack trace.

Comment: @DougStevenson I'm showing you guys a stack trace now.

Comment: see DictionaryProvider.java, method "query", case: "SEARCH_WORDS", do you see the "if" you wrote?

Comment: @pskink So, how to fix this? I'm a newbie and I don't understanding this point.

Comment: just debug your `DictionaryProvider#query` code, setup a breakpoint and click "step over" button to debug it step by step

Answer (score 2):

The log says it: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ec.idiomas/com.ec.idiomas.BancoDictionary}: java.lang.RuntimeException: **Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'**

Comment: Another problem has came up! Check the trace of the crash above. :/

Answer (score 1):

The error message says it all:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

See the documentation for [ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html):

> ListActivity has a default layout that consists of a single,
>   full-screen list in the center of the screen. However, if you desire,
>   you can customize the screen layout by setting your own view layout
>   with setContentView() in onCreate(). To do this, your own view MUST
>   contain a ListView object with the id "@android:id/list" (or list if
>   it's in code)

You will have to change your ListView to conform to the requirements for ListActivity.

Comment: Thanks, but now the app still crashes. I've updated the stack trace above.

Comment: This is a different problem, so probably ask a different question after you've tried to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the source of your problems is "Caused by: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: selectionArgs must be provided` for the Uri: content://com.ec.idiomas.searchabledict.DictionaryProvider/dictionary".

You need to set `selectionArgs` to solve your problem.